# Imports needed to use Facebook graph API in iOS6

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

I've added the Accounts and Social frameworks, and done this in my view controller:

```
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>

@interface FacebookViewController () <FBRequestDelegate> //Error - Cannot find protocol declaration for "FBRequestDelegate"

@end
```

What else do I need to do? Are there exertnal files needed to work with the FB API?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```